# JasperReport setParameter() Deprecated?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have recently upgraded the Jasper Reports library for my project, from **3.7.6** to **6.0.0**. I can finally Maven build and the reports are working just great. However, the **setParameter()** function appears to have been deprecated between releases, and I am unsure how to refactor my code to accommodate for this.

### Example of Deprecated Code:

```
private static void exportMultipleToCSV(Collection<JasperPrint> jasperPrints, OutputStream baos) throws JRException {
    JRCsvExporter csvExporter = new JRCsvExporter();

    csvExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
    csvExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
    csvExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, Integer.valueOf(1500000));
    csvExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, Integer.valueOf(40000000));
    csvExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_WIDTH, Integer.valueOf(4));
    csvExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_HEIGHT, Integer.valueOf(15));

    csvExporter.exportReport();
}
```

I have looked through the [SourceForge](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) page, and can see that it has been replaced by **ExporterInput**, **ExporterConfiguration** and **ExporterOutput** but I am unsure how to utilise them all together to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent code would look something like this:

```
JRCsvExporter csvExporter = new JRCsvExporter();
//jasperPrints is Collection, but we need a List
csvExporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(new ArrayList(jasperPrints)));
csvExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(baos));
SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration exporterConfiguration = new SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration();
//nothing to set here, but you could do things like exporterConfiguration.setFieldDelimiter
csvExporter.setConfiguration(exporterConfiguration);
csvExporter.exportReport();
```

Note that the old API allowed you do things like `csvExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT)`.  The problem with that was that the CSV exporter did not actually use that parameter, only the text exporter was looking at `JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT`.  With the new API, it's clear what settings/configuration you can do on each exporter.